# как передать в js массив? laravel

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Необходимо передать массив в JS

Приходит массив из контроллера (коллекция).
я получаю все ID

```
$top_menu->pluck('id')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть скрипт js

```
// 1 часть меню
but_g_menu. onclick = function() {
    if(id_g_menu. style . display == "none")  {
        id_g_menu.style . display= "";
    }
    else  { id_g_menu.style . display = "none"; }
}
// 2 часть меню
var id_menu = new Array('1111','2222','3333');
startList = function allclose() {
    for (i=0; i < id_menu.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
}
function openMenu(id){
    for (i=0; i < id_menu.length; i++){
        if (id != id_menu[i]){
            document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
window.onload=startList;
```

необходимо передать ID категории в js var id_menu = new Array(
или изменить js как-то по другому.
по js мало понимаю.
Заранее благодарен за любую информацию!

***у меня получается передать так:***
var id_menu = json_encode([1,2,3,4,16,19]); но скрипт не работает
var id_menu = new (json_encode([1,2,3,4,16,19])); так тоже не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var id_menu = {{json_encode($top_menu->pluck('id'))}};

var id_menu = @json($top_menu->pluck('id'));